# Creating arrays using for loops in OpenGL

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, for-loop, vertex

What I have to do is create a square that is made up of 8 triangles, all the same size, using arrays. The coordinates of the four corners of the square are, (-10, -10, 10), (-10, -10, -10), (10, -10, -10), (10, -10, 10). And that's starting with the upper left and going counter clockwise.

I have already created it before just entering values into the array but now I have to figure out how to do it using for loops in C++. So I know that for each array (I need to create a vertex, index and color array) I need to create a for loop and that that for loop has to have a for loop inside of it.

Comment: why not define the points and colors in parallel arrays and then simply iterate over them once?

Comment: @user931794 first off I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean (like I said I'm very new to this), I don't really know what a parallel array is. But if I sort of understand what you mean then I don't think that will work since I can't hard code any of the values, I have to create the arrays purely through the for loops. Sorry if I'm not being clear enough, like I said I'm very new to this so I'm a little unsure of how to explain things.

Comment: You might want to specify the language you're using or else people will give you solutions in [INTERCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL).

Comment: @genpfault yea I just thought of that, thanks for helping with the edits :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to subdivide a rectangle by two in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [`Eigen::Vector2f`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for `Vec` but anything with a similar interface should work:

```
template< typename Vec >
void glVec2d( const Vec& vec )
{
    glVertex2d( vec.x(), vec.y() );
}

template< typename Vec >
void glTex2d( const Vec& vec )
{
    glTexCoord2d( vec.x(), vec.y() );
}

template< typename Vec >
void glQuad2d
    (
    const Vec& A,  // lower left coord
    const Vec& B,  // lower right coord
    const Vec& C,  // upper right coord
    const Vec& D,  // upper left coord
    unsigned int divs = 2,
    const Vec& At = Vec(0,0),
    const Vec& Bt = Vec(1,0),
    const Vec& Ct = Vec(1,1),
    const Vec& Dt = Vec(0,1)
    )
{
    // base case
    if( divs == 0 )
        {
        glTex2d( At );
        glVec2d( A );

        glTex2d( Bt );
        glVec2d( B );

        glTex2d( Ct );
        glVec2d( C );

        glTex2d( Dt );
        glVec2d( D );

        return;
        }

    Vec AB = (A+B) * 0.5;
    Vec BC = (B+C) * 0.5;
    Vec CD = (C+D) * 0.5;
    Vec AD = (A+D) * 0.5;
    Vec ABCD = (AB+CD) * 0.5;

    Vec ABt = (At+Bt) * 0.5;
    Vec BCt = (Bt+Ct) * 0.5;
    Vec CDt = (Ct+Dt) * 0.5;
    Vec ADt = (At+Dt) * 0.5;
    Vec ABCDt = (ABt+CDt) * 0.5;

    // subdivided point layout
    // D   CD   C
    // 
    // AD ABCD BC 
    //
    // A   AB   B

    // subdivide
    glQuad2d( A, AB, ABCD, AD, divs - 1, At, ABt, ABCDt, ADt );
    glQuad2d( AB, B, BC, ABCD, divs - 1, ABt, Bt, BCt, ABCDt );
    glQuad2d( ABCD, BC, C, CD, divs - 1, ABCDt, BCt, Ct, CDt );
    glQuad2d( AD, ABCD, CD, D, divs - 1, ADt, ABCDt, CDt, Dt );
}
```

It's currently recursive but you could always add an explicit stack for some for-loop action.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this is way beyond what I know so far. I am in college studying game programming and this is my first course so I really don't know too much. But I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: that is some quality code. very elegant. though like you alluded to if you were going to call this many many times you might want to use an explicit stack allocated on the heap instead of the system stack (i.e. change the function so it's not recursive) to avoid the possibility of a STACK OVERFLOW.